# what is this javascript if shorthand that uses only && called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

a ternary operator is something like `isHot ? 'I am sweating': ''`

but there is something shorter like
`isHot && 'I am sweating'`

what is it called?

Comment: what should happen with the result? what is the content of `isHot`?

Comment: that's just [the Logical && (AND) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Aplying it like that is called short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: These are not the same, the corresponding ternary of `isHot && 'I am sweating'` would be `isHot ? 'I am sweating' : isHot` and the corresponding AND version of `isHot ? 'I am sweating': ''` would be `isHot && 'I am sweating' || ''`

Comment: @GolfWolf do post your comment as answer :)